# excel date picker not outputting correct value

Tags: excel, datepicker, userform, vba

On my Excel UserForm I have the built in date picker (Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0)

I want to output this value to my sheet, but the output is constantly incorrect, no matter what the date chosen on the date picker.
I am getting the date output on the sheet of 30 December 1999.

```
Cells(23, 2) = Format(EmployeeStartDatePicker.Value, "dd/mmmm/yy")
```

This is identical to what I found on another site and worked for the user but mine does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the opposite then:

```
Cells(23, 2).NumberFormat = "dd/mmmm/yy"
Cells(23, 2) = EmployeeStartDatePicker.Value
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now get the date output of 00/January/00, even though the date in the datepicker is 17/02/2017

Comment: @Demo what happnes if you try the lines in reverse ? like in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

I have code that hides the tab with the date picker on, trying to output the value AFTER it is hidden returns no value but if I output the value before I hide the tab then it works.

Thanks to Shai for the code that made me realise this.